# PHP object with $a->name and $a->name->function()

Tags: php

How can I create an object/class which has a variable. The variable then needs to also have a callable function.

```
$a->name //return foo
$a->name->getAlias() //return foobar
```

The above is an example and not the desired functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: `$a->name` would need to reference an object instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The _toString automagically can change your object if your object is being called as an string. The `name` needs to be an instance of a object in order to use it different ways:

```
class A
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->name = new B();
    }
}

class B
{
    function __toString()
    {
        return 'Jamie';
    }

    function getAlias()
    {
        return 'JJAMMIIEE';
    }
}

$a = new A();
print $a->name; //returns Jamie
var_dump($a->name); //returns Object B, __toString function will not be called
print $a->name->getAlias(); //returns JJAMMIIEE
```

[Documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)